# Homology of the quotient space $(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \Delta) / (\mathbb{Z} / 2)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I do not have any clue to the following question:
What is the homology group of $(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \Delta) / (\mathbb{Z} / 2)$, where $\Delta$ is the diagonal in $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$, and the equivalence relation is $(x, y) \sim (y, x)$ for all $x \ne y$.

Comment: What kind of homology are you taking?

Comment: It's not hard to see that the space in question is homotopy equivalent to something familiar.

Comment: @AnonymousCoward thanks! I got to the step where $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \Delta \sim S^{n - 1}$ but couldn't get around to get the (singular) homology of $S^{n - 1} / (\mathbb{Z} / 2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is an obvious $Z/2$ invariant deformation retract of $R^n\times R^n/\{(x,x)\}$ onto the orthogonal complement of the diagonal subspace, $V = \{(x,-x)\}$, and there is a further $Z/2$ invariant deformation retract in this subspace of $V\setminus \{0\}$ onto the unit sphere in $V$.
- Hint: What is the described action of $Z/2$ when restricted to $V$? It coincides with a familiar action when you identify $V$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the "obvious" way.
- Further hint: What is the most familiar $Z/2$ quotient of a sphere you can think of?

Comment: For the final hint, is the $\mathbb{Z} / 2$ quotient of $S^{n - 1}$ $\mathbb{RP}^{n - 1}$?

Comment: What is the action of $Z/2$ on $S^{n-1}$ that yields $RP^{n-1}$ as the quotient? Can you show that the $Z/2$ action you have here is the same as that one? If so, then your answer is yes.